# check if the timer has any pending tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

I use the Java's Timer to schedule a task to run after some interval of time.

```
myTimer.schedule(myTask, delayTime);
```

At any point in time, is it possible to check if there is any task scheduled to be run (but has not run yet)? If so, how would I do that?

If not, what is the alternative(s) to Timer do I have?

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of `Timer`.
It handles thread crashes in a robust manner and has more flexible API

Comment: In addition to a ScheduledExecutorService, a [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) is needed to actually check whether any tasks are pending.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a boolean field to myTask's class, which will be set true at first execute.
Keep it simple.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how that answers my question?

Comment: It does answer the first question for the additional assumption that you are interested in knowing if a specific task has run yet, not just anyone. Other than that, you are much better off with `ScheduledExecutorService` as @Cratylus has answered.